# Why the login in terminal is on ttys000?

Tags: xcode, authentication, terminal

When I opened my terminal it said that last login was on ttys000? What is ttys000 and is it okay to have it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, totally normal, assuming that you have logged in before with that terminal.

`ttys000` is the first Tele Type Session that you opened with that terminal

Comment: It's absolutely not totally normal. Normal is no messages on new terminal instance

Comment: and how do you know he did not login before?